# Condition for $f(x)=p[x+1]+q[x-1]$ to be continuous at $x=1$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

> The function $f(x)=p[x+1]+q[x-1]$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function is continuous at $x=1$, if ___________________

- $f(1)=2p$
- $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=p(2)+q(0)=2p$
- $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=p(1)+q(-1)=p-q$
- $p-q=2p\implies p+q=0$

But my reference gives the solution $p=q$, what is going wrong here ?

Comment: The standard notation for integer part is $\lfloor x \rfloor$ (\lfloor and \rfloor). I'd write $p$ and $q$ at right to avoid confusion. Like this $$f(x)=\lfloor x+1\rfloor p +\lfloor x-1 \rfloor q$$

Comment: @ajotatxe I used () for the value of the greatest integer function, after applying the limits.

Comment: I think you misunderstood ajotatxe comment. The modern notation for the integer part is $\lfloor x \rfloor$ instead of $[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and the textbook is wrong.
Try plotting what the textbook says the answer is [$p=q$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BFloor%5Bx%2B1%5D%2BFloor%5Bx-1%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D).  The textbook's answer produces a stair case. However, your answer,
[$p=-q$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BFloor%5Bx%2B1%5D-Floor%5Bx-1%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D), is a flat line. In terms of wave superposition your answer has a "destructive interference", where the stair cases cancel and this results in a flat line.